# ayuda con este ejercicio que no entiendo

Tags: c++

Desarrolle el algoritmo solicitado:

- Desarrollar un módulo no void CorrerDatos que recibe entre otros los siguientes parámetros:

  - un vector VLeg de 150 posiciones que contiene únicamente Legajos de tipo entero;
  - un valor tope < 150 con la posición del último Legajo cargado en el vector;
  - un valor pos <= tope;
  - un nuevo Legajo a “insertar” en la posición pos del vector.

Debe

- Insertar en la posición pos de VLeg, el Legajo recibido sin perderse los datos ya cargados en el vector. Como pos es <= tope, en dicha posición y las que siguen hasta tope habrá Legajos ya cargados; por lo tanto para poder insertar deberá realizar el corrimiento de los elementos necesarios (copiando cada uno debajo de su posición actual).
- Retornar true en caso en que el vector se haya llenado; caso contrario retornar false.

```
    bool correrdatos(int vleg[150],int tope,int pos,int legajo)
    {
        int aux,aux2,i;
    
        for( pos ; pos<tope ; pos++)
        {
        aux=vleg[pos];
        vleg[pos]=legajo;
        legajo=aux;
        }
    
        if(pos==tope-1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Esto es lo que tengo hecho por mi, lo que necesitaría saber si esta correcto, ya que solo me pide la función.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por el [tour] y por [ask] para entender cómo funciona este portal y cómo deben elaborarse las preguntas. Lamento informarte de que aquí no se le hacen los deberes a la gente. Muestra tu código y haz preguntas concretas para que te ayudemos

Comment: Que bien, veo que actualizaste el post y agregaste código; pues todo parece que esta bien... pero la tarea que te asignaron dice algoritmo, ya comprobaste que el código de tu algoritmo funciona correctamente en C++, no sale ningún error al ejecutar?

Comment: Ahi estoy haciendo un main para probar que funcione, pero ya con que me digas que este bien esa parte es suficiente

Comment: @Nahuz Pienso que la manera de definir si esta correcto, es verificando que funcione...

Comment: En respuesta, te propongo que lo pruebes primeramente, y verifiques los parámetros de entrada y salida (Osea, pregúntate a ti mismo: ¿Según el ejercicio es esto lo que debo realizar?). Tómalo como una ecuación donde se te podría asesorar sobre la forma de resolver el problema en el mismo enunciado, por ello guíate primeramente paso a paso de la idea general que se busca abarcar con todos los puntos del problema y luego te preocupas de que los pequeños detalles calcen según se te pidió. Te recomiendo vayas punto por punto para que no te desordenes ni te pierdas en que quedaste, de esa forma ya